# Count of record, per day, by user comparative

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking to see if there is a way to compare the number of orders entered a day and by either a specific user (EDI) or anyone else.

I can return results for per day (but only the days where a value exists) but can't figure out a way to combine all three together  (Total - by EDI - by everyone else).

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

```
select Date, count(Order_ID) 
from orders 
WHERE Date >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0) and [user] = 'EDI' 
      and customer = '9686'
GROUP BY Date, [user];
select Date, count(Order_ID) 
from orders 
WHERE Date >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0) and [user] <> 'EDI' 
      and customer = '9686'
GROUP BY Date, [user];
select Date, count(Order_ID) 
from orders 
WHERE Date >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0) 
      and customer = '9686'
GROUP BY Date, [user];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select Date, sum(case when [user] = 'EDI' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_edi,
       sum(case when [user] <> 'EDI' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_non_edi,
       count(*) as total
from orders 
where Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 7, 0) and customer = '9686'
group by Date;
```

Comment: Thanks very much - exactly what i was looking for. I will study up on that type of function.  Again - many thanks.